# Copy range to other worksheet if A1 contains specific word

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have 2 worksheets:

1st - for monthly data, where I collect data only for 1 month (1...12)

[image: Monthly data]

2nd - annually data by months (12 tables for each month)
[image: Annually data]

I need macro which will copy data from monthly sheet to annually sheet according to month.
For example, if it`s September it will copy to September table in annually sheet.
If October to October table in annually sheet and so on.

How could I implement it using macro (want create button: click and copy).

Comment: Do you have 2 worksheets or 2 workbooks? The example you are providing is 1 sheet, so do you have 12 of these sheets in 1 workbook? Or do you have 12 of these sheets in the same workbook as where you have the annual data?

Comment: I have 1 workbook with 2 worksheets (monthly and annually).
1st worksheet include only one table (monthly) and 2nd - 12 tables (each month). Tables in monthly and annually sheets are similar.

Answer (score 1):

The macro will need to include a CASE statement with 12 options (one for each month). Prior to reaching this CASE statement, you need to define a variable that will represent the month (e.g. using current date).

Each option within the CASE construct will copy from a specified sheet into a specified table (here I'm assuming that the structure of the monthly table are known and static).

An alternative approach would be to have the CASE setting the SOURCE sheet and the target range within the annual sheet. This would be a shorter piece of code using a common COPY block.